# DataTable to List Generic

Tags: c#, list, generics, datatable

i'm using the following extension to extract a column from a datatable to a list-object:

```
public static List<string> ColumnToList(this DataTable dt, string ColumnName)
{
    return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[ColumnName].ToString()).ToList();
}
```

ist it possible to use a genereic datata-type - not just string - ? in my case the return-value can be anything like `List<string>, List<datetime>, List<int>, List<bool>`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use `DataRow.Field<T>` method:

```
public static List<T> ColumnToList<T>(this DataTable dt, string ColumnName)
{
    return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<T>(ColumnName)).ToList();
}
```

You need to specify the column type when calling the method, for example:

```
List<int> idList = dt.ColumnToList<int>("id");
```

Comment: The type arguments for method ColumnToList cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: You need to specify column type when calling the method `dt.ColumnToList<int>("id");`

Comment: but i don't know that - it depends on the column of the datatable. isn't it possible to make that generic too?

Comment: @fubo if you don't know, compiler can't know either.

Comment: hm ok, i think i can read the type previous to the call. thanks, that solves my problem